# Is there an Ansible equivalent of the powershell command Switch-AzureRmWebAppSlot?

Tags: azure, web-applications, automation, ansible

I am eager to automate the process of swapping between WebApp slots on azure:

https://octopus.com/docs/deploying-applications/deploying-to-azure/deploying-a-package-to-an-azure-web-app/using-deployment-slots-with-azure-web-apps

but for everything to date I have tried to avoid using powershell, and stayed in a Linux/Ansible automation environment. I have looked through the ansible azure modules:

http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/list_of_cloud_modules.html#azure

for something to help out here, but other than my favorite module azure_rm_deployment_module, I don't see anything that can help me automate this kind of procedure. Currently I am using Azure with all Node/Linux resources and setting up a Windows VM to invoke PowerShell (PS) commands like Switch-AzureRmWebAppSlot, seems to deviate from that plan. I could always try to debug what the PS command is doing and attempt to simulate it, however if anyone has a better solution it would be great to hear it!

Answer (score 0):

No, the closest you can get is run a script to do the job (powershell\azure cli). Azure Powershell works on linux (that's what I'm using for some of my ansible tasks), alternatively Azure CLI works as well

Comment: PowerShell on linux, Thanks I would have never have thunk that would be possible, so used to Microsoft closed source, that having them go OSS is more enabling than I thought possible for them.

Comment: well, it happened about a year ago so i'm not sure whyd you think its not possible

Answer (score 0):

If there is a way to use arm to perform the action, you should be good using the azure_rm_deployment module. A trick I've used in the past is to use fiddler with https tracing on while performing an action using Azure powershell. For Azure providers that use the arm endpoints, there's a good chance that this will leave you with a semi-clean log of the endpoints/json payload you need to perform the action.

It's fairly hacky, but for a long time this was the only way to get anything done with webapps outside of Powershell, due to the lackiness of Azure's documentation.

Comment: thats pretty obvious, but i doubt swap can be done with an arm template

Comment: I'm not saying arm template, i'm saying "arm operation".

Comment: azure_rm_deployment can only deploy templates

Comment: oh, my bad. I didn't realize. I did some stuff around arm and pure rest operations for Ansible a while back, I'm sure the library refs are outdated but maybe it would be of help to you anyway. https://github.com/trondhindenes/ansible-arm-deployment (thinking about the arm_invoke module)

Comment: Thank you for the reminder to use a proxy, I always seem to forget this, and fiddler pretty much always help me get the job done.